# sed remove line if neither pattern provided don't match

Tags: sed

I am trying to create a filter command to reduce the lines from a log file, assume each line contains partition made of date,

```
/iamthepath01/20200301/file01.txt
/iamthepath02/20200302/file02.txt
....
/iamthepathxx/20210619/filexx.txt
```

then from thousands of lines I only want to keep the ones with two string in the path

```
/202106
/202105
```

and remove any other lines

I have tried following command

```
sed -i -e '\(/202105\|/202106\)!d' ~/log.txt
```

above command threw

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated address regex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/\/20210[56]/!d' ~/log.txt
```

Or, if you need to use more specific alternatives and further enhance the pattern:

```sh
sed -i -E '/\/(202105|202106)/!d' ~/log.txt
```

*Details*:

- `-i` - GNU sed option for inline file replacement
- `-E` - option enabling POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `/\/20210[56]/` - regex that matches `/20210` and then either `5` or `6`
- `\/(202105|202106)` - the POSIX ERE pattern that matches `/` and then either `202105` or `202106`
- `!d` - removes the lines not matching the pattern.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/970sQT):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='/iamthepath01/20200301/file01.txt
/iamthepath02/20200302/file02.txt
/iamthepathxx/20210619/filexx.txt'
sed '/\/20210[56]/!d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
/iamthepathxx/20210619/filexx.txt
```

Comment: Thanks much that works! I assume that ERE pattern may works faster? As I have a short file so didn't see a lot performance difference

Comment: @Dreamer If you have a choice between a regex with alternation and without, use the one without, it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

sed is the wrong tool for this. If you want a script that's as fragile as the sed one then use grep as it's the tool that exists solely to do a simple `g/re/p` (hence the name) like you're doing:

```
$ grep '/20210[56]' file
/iamthepathxx/20210619/filexx.txt
```

or if you want a more robust solution that focuses just on the part of the line you want to match and so will avoid false matches, then use awk:

```
$ awk -F '/' '$3 ~ /^20210[56]/' file
/iamthepathxx/20210619/filexx.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ni '\#/20210[56]#p' file
```

This uses seds `-n` grep-like option to turn off implicit printing and `-i` option to edit the file in place.

Normally sed uses the `/.../` to match but other delimiters may be used if the first is escaped e.g. `\#...#`.

So the above solution will filter the existing file down to lines that contain either `/202105` or `/202106`.

N.B. grep will almost certainly be faster in finding the above lines however the use of the `-i` option may be the ultimate reason for choosing sed (although the same outcome can be achieved by tacking on the `> tmpFile && mv tmpFile file` to a grep solution).